# how to pass values from Visualforce Email Template to custom component

Tags: visualforce-component, email-template

I have created a simple visualforce email template:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="** Inventory Wishlist Match Found **" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Inventory_Wishlist__c">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody > 

Year: {!relatedTo.Year__c}<br />
Make: {!relatedTo.Make__c}<br />
Model: {!relatedTo.Model__c}

<p>Below is a link to your request and the matching inventory.</p>

Request: <a href="http://cs11.salesforce.com/{!relatedTo.Id}">{!relatedTo.Name}</a><br />
Inventory: <c:ProductLinkComponent yearValue="{!relatedTo.Year__c}" makeValue="{!relatedTo.Make__c}" modelValue="{!relatedTo.Model__c}" />

</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Here is my component:

```
<apex:component access="global" controller="ProductLinkController">

<apex:attribute name="yearValue" description="Attribute for product year" type="String" required="required" assignTo="{!year}" />
<apex:attribute name="makeValue" description="Attribute for product make" type="String" required="required" assignTo="{!make}" />
<apex:attribute name="modelValue" description="Attribute for product model" type="String" required="required" assignTo="{!model}" />

<a href="http://cs11.salesforce.com/{!productId}">{!productName}</a>

</apex:component>
```

Here is my component controller:

```
public class ProductLinkController {

public Product2 product {
    get {
        List<Product2> productList = [select Id, Name from Product2 where year__c =: year AND Make__c =: make and Model__c =: model limit 1];
        if(!productList.isEmpty() && product == null) {
            product = productList[0];
        }
        else {
            product = new Product2();
        }
        return product;
    }
    set;
}
public String year { get;set; }
public String make { get;set; }
public String model { get;set; }

public ProductLinkController() {

}

public String getProductId() {
    return product.Id;
}

public String getProductName() {
    return product.Name;
}
}
```

I'm trying to output a link to a product in my email based on the values (year, make, model) that are passed thru the email template to the controller.

The query is not returning the correct product and I'm having problems debugging the component controller to see the values that are getting passed in.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it's not working as intended has to do with the [order of execution for page loads](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_get_request.htm)

The controller constructor is executed before the class properties are set (year, make, model). So the bind variables in the SOQL query in the constructor are all null when the constructor executes. THEN, year make and model are set from the values on the page.

One way to remedy this is in the component controller, move the SOQL query to a getter on the product variable.

```
private final Product2 product {
   get {
      product = [select Id, Name from Product2 where year__c =: year AND Make__c =: make and Model__c =: model limit 1];
      return product; }
   set;
}
```

Comment: I tried modifying my component controller with the change you suggested (see above), but I'm getting the error List has no rows for assignment to SObject.

Comment: In the email template's call to the component, right curly brackets are missing in the value assignments, so your literally passing "{!relatedTo.Year__c" and not the wishlist field value. But this does bring up a best practice issue that I lazily neglected regarding the query. You should assign the query result to a list of product2's as opposed to a product2 because it won't error out if no records are found.

Comment: get { List<Product2> lstProduct = [query...];  if (!lstProduct.isempty() && product == null) product = lstProduct[0]; }

Comment: Also add: else product = new Product();

Comment: Thanks jabbo! I made the adjustments to my code (see the updates above).  I am monitoring the code in the debug log and the url is getting correctly pulled in, but the link doesn't show up in my email because the product name is not coming thru.  Here is what it shows in the debug log: `Request: <a href="http://cs11.salesforce.com/a03Z0000008JykrIAC">WISH-000000001</a><br />
Inventory: <a href="https://cs11.salesforce.com/01tZ0000001Gt6KIAS"></a>` The inventory product name is not coming thru.  I can query by id and get the name. Any ideas why is not coming thru in the email?

Comment: oops forgot something... the else part should be else if(product == null) because you only want to assign product to something when it's null. `get {
        List<Product2> productList = [select Id, Name from Product2 where year__c =: year AND Make__c =: make and Model__c =: model limit 1];
        if(!productList.isEmpty() && product == null) {
            product = productList[0];
        }
        else if(product==null) {
            product = new Product2();
        }
        return product;
    }`

Comment: @Dman100 do you have an example of your testClass for this visualforce controller? Trying to find an example for how that would work.

Comment: @GPP Unfortunately, I've cleaned up some of my old projects and don't have that code any longer. The test class should be pretty straight-forward. You'll need to create a test product and call the method in the class `getProductId()` in your test method. Are you hitting any errors?

Comment: @Dman100 ah no worries, thanks for the insight regarding the method call though. I am on my own Saga of creating a custom visualforce email that pulls in Child Object data and need to write a test class (oh joy!) so I can push to production